# How sum over work

Tags: sql-server, sum

Given this table:

```
CREATE TABLE Table1
(
  [Classroom] int,
  [CourseName] varchar(8),
  [Lesson] varchar(9),
  [StartTime] char(4),
  [EndTime] char(4)
);
```

then:

```
INSERT INTO Table1
(
  [Classroom], 
  [CourseName], 
  [Lesson], 
  [StartTime], 
  [EndTime]
)
VALUES
    (1001, 'Course 1', 'Lesson 1', '0800', '0900'),
    (1001, 'Course 1', 'Lesson 2', '0900', '1000'),
    (1001, 'Course 1', 'Lesson 3', '1000', '1100'),
    (1001, 'Course 1', 'Lesson 6', '1100', '1200'),
    (1001, 'Course 2', 'Lesson 10', '1100', '1200'),
    (1001, 'Course 2', 'Lesson 11', '1200', '1300'),
    (1001, 'Course 1', 'Lesson 4', '1300', '1400'),
    (1001, 'Course 1', 'Lesson 5', '1400', '1500');
```

And my query is:

```
With A AS 
(
  SELECT 
    ClassRoom
    CourseName
    StartTime
    EndTime
    PrevCourse = LAG(CourseName, 1, CourseName) OVER (ORDER BY StartTime)
  FROM   Table1
), B AS (
  SELECT 
    ClassRoom
    CourseName
    StartTime
    EndTime
    Ranker = SUM(CASE WHEN CourseName = PrevCourse THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                OVER (ORDER BY StartTime, CourseName)
  FROM   A
)
SELECT B.* FROM B;
```

This gives me the following result:

```
ClassRoom CourseName StartTime EndTime Ranker
1001      Course 1   0800   0900    0
1001      Course 1   0900   1000    0
1001      Course 1   1000   1100    0
1001      Course 1   1100   1200    0
1001      Course 2   1100   1200    1
1001      Course 2   1200   1300    1
1001      Course 1   1300   1400    2
1001      Course 1   1400   1500    2
```

Please focus on the ranker column. If I have not misunderstood, at the every first row where current course is different to previous course, then sum(1); the next rows, where current course == previous course, then sum(0), so my expectation of the ranker should be: (0,0,0,0), (1,1), (1,1) but it give me (0,0,0,0), (1,1), (2,2). Why at the end it give me (2, 2)? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Hi, and welcome to dba.se! You have `Course 1 - Lesson 6` & `Course 2 - Lesson 10` taking place in the same room (`1001`) at the same time (`1100` to `1200`). Is this deliberate or a typo? I know that some courses may have different names/codes for the same teaching (some advance undergrads may take some postgrad courses &c.) - just checking!

Comment: Duplicate post and answered at [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72759288/the-way-sum-over-function-work-in-sql-server)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72759288/the-way-sum-over-function-work-in-sql-server)!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your window frame for summing is all previous rows. Is this closer to what you want?

```
, Ranker = SUM(CASE WHEN CourseName = PrevCourse THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
               OVER (PARTITION BY CourseName ORDER BY StartTime)

ClassRoom   CourseName  StartTime   EndTime Ranker
1001    Course 1    0800    0900    0
1001    Course 1    0900    1000    0
1001    Course 1    1000    1100    0
1001    Course 1    1100    1200    0
1001    Course 2    1100    1200    1
1001    Course 2    1200    1300    1
1001    Course 1    1300    1400    1
1001    Course 1    1400    1500    1
```

Answer (score 0):

I've changed your table DDL.

- I changed the `CHAR (4) definition of your` start_time`and`end_time`fields to`TIME(0)`. I **cannot** stress strongly enough the importance of having the correct data type for your data! How do you check if the time is valid? Inserting "5399" would be accepted as a valid "time"! Using the correct data type means that you have built-in range checking for free!

  Just imagine there's a public transport problem one morning! Everyone is an hour late - so, the principal of the school decides to reschedule all courses to 1 hour later
- I added a [`ROW_NUMBER()`](https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-window-functions/sql-server-row_number-function/) window function to the second CTE.
- I changed the presentation - but **not** the content - of the rest of your SQL (all of the code below is available on the fiddle here):

CREATE TABLE test
    (
      class_room  INTEGER,
      course_name VARCHAR (8),
      lesson      VARCHAR (9),
      start_time  TIME(0),        SQL:

```
WITH a AS 
(
  SELECT 
    class_room,
    course_name,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    LAG(course_name, 1, 'Course 1') OVER (ORDER BY start_time) AS prev_course
  FROM   test
), b AS 
(
  SELECT 
    class_room,
    course_name,
    start_time,
    end_time,
    SUM
    (
      CASE 
        WHEN course_name = prev_course THEN 0 
        ELSE 1 
      END
    )  OVER (ORDER BY start_time, course_name) AS ranker
  FROM   a
)
SELECT b.* FROM b;
```

Result (and analysis of the results):

```
class_room  course_name start_time  end_time    ranker
1001           Course 1       0800  0900    0
1001           Course 1       0900  1000    0
1001           Course 1       1000  1100    0
1001           Course 1       1100  1200    0
1001           Course 2       1100  1200    1
1001           Course 2       1200  1300    1
1001           Course 1       1300  1400    2
1001           Course 1       1400  1500    2
```